# calabash-cucumber :How to force fail calabash step if the scenario takes long time or might be got hanged

Tags: cucumber, calabash, calabash-ios

Calabash test hangs in between the scenarios when test run for long time, i was expecting scenario to timeout if any condition didn't met. however that also not happening so that test move on to next scenario.

Is there a way i can implement in my code to keep monitoring each scenario run time, so that it force scenario to fail if it takes a longer then expected, and afterwards next scenario runs normally ?

Any help highly appreciated!!

-mesh

Answer (score 3):

You can use an around hook, this one will timeout after 10 seconds:

```
Around do |scenario, block|
  Timeout.timeout(10) do
    block.call
  end
end
```

Comment: have you tried this ?, because this Around hook didn't give me same result for all scenario. Some time it does timeout and sometime not.

Comment: Hmm could it be that the tests have background steps? http://makandracards.com/makandra/12039-cucumber-pitfall-around-does-not-apply-to-your-background-steps

Comment: I have had inconsistent results with Around hooks and calabash.  I traced the problem back to cucumber itself.  After looking at the relevant issues, I concluded that hooks would be re-worked in cucumber 2.0.  We are evaluating calabash + cucumber 2.0 compatibility.  Please don't ask when we will add cucumber 2.0 support.  It will depend on when cucumber 2.0 is released; something we have no control over.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax to force step to fail

#### Syntax

```
fail(msg = 'Error. Check log for details.', options = {:prefix => nil, :name => nil, :label => nil})
```

**Example**

```
fail(msg ="Failed due to timeout")
```

#### In your case

```
Given (/^I do this$/)do 
  do some...
  sleep 10
  fail(msg="failure message")
end
```